# jquery loading animation with php form that submits back to itself

Tags: php, jquery

I have a PHP file that contains a form and which submits back to itself.  Is there any way to show a loading animation after the form is submitted and run until the page is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show progress indicator while the form is submitting why dont you use AJAX?

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

$(".loading").show();//Assuming you have a container which has appropriate style and image to show the loading image

    $.post( {
       url: $(this).attr("action"), 
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function(){ 
           $(".loading").show();
           //Write code here to handle on success 

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried that with modifying the names of the form and div appropriately with no luck.  With the above code the form no longer submits.

Comment: $(this).action is undef but if I change it to $(this).attr("action") it at least is defined; however, still nothing occurs in the success block.

Comment: I tried that.  The hangup appears to be on the success:function() part.  If I remove that the form submits but otherwise it will not submit.

Comment: That is just a success handler, it should not harm. But if you dont have to do anything on success then you can remove it.

Comment: If I remove the success handler then the form submits but the loading animation doesn't display.

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial. Assuming you have a hidden spinner/loading image somewhere on your page with id 'loadingImg':

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $("#loadingImg").show();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yFaAj/1/

Comment: That flashes up for a split second and then goes away.  Then the page loads.

Comment: Well, that's the idea. The spinner will remain until the page refreshes.

Comment: Yes but I need the spinner to run until the page is fully loaded.  What happens is that there are a lot of curl calls and whatnot that need to execute before I want the spinner to go away.